# React: triggering method inside HOC component

Tags: reactjs

What I want to do, is create a HOC that has a method that can be triggered by whatever Parent Component is using that HOC to wrap.

For this HOC, I'm trying to fade out the HOC and any components inside it:

HOC:

```
export function fadeOutWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        showElement: true,
        removeElement: false,
      };
    }

    _triggerFade = () => {
      this._fadeOut(this.props.time).then(time => this._removeElement(time));
    }

    _fadeOut = time => {
      let _this = this;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          _this.setState({
            showElement: false
          });
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(time);
        }, time);
      });
    };

    _removeElement = time => {
      let _this = this;
      setTimeout(() => {
        _this.setState({
          removeElement: true
        });
      }, time + 500);
    };

    render() {
      return this.state.removeElement ? null : (
        <div
          className={
            this.state.showElement
              ? "cfd-container"
              : "cfd-container cfd-fadeout"
          }
        >
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

How this component is being used in parent component:

```
import ComponentToBeFaded from '...';
import { fadeOutWrapper } from '...';

const WrappedComponent = fadeOutWrapper(ComponentToBeFaded);

class ParentComponent extends Component {
 const...
 super...

 handleChildClick = () => {
  // ? how to trigger the HOC _triggerFade method?
  // WrappedComponent._triggerFade()
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <WrappedComponent time={1000} handleClick={this.handleChildClick} {...other props component needs} />
  )
 }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is call a method that is inside the HOC, can't seem to check for a change in props inside the HOC... only inside the HOC's render()

Need to keep writing more to meet the submission quota. Any thoughts on how to do this is appreciated. Hope your day is going well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need showElement in local state of the wrapped component because it's not controlled by that component. Pass it as props and use componentDidUpdate to start fading out.

```js
const { Component, useState, useCallback } = React;
const Button = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Remove</button>
);
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const onClick = useCallback(() => setShow(s => !s), []);
  return (
    <WrappedButton
      time={1000}
      onClick={onClick}
      showElement={show}
    />
  );
}

function fadeOutWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        removeElement: false,
        fadeout: false,
      };
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (
        this.props.showElement !== prevProps.showElement &&
        !this.props.showElement
      ) {
        this._triggerFade();
      }
    }
    _triggerFade = () => {
      this._fadeOut(this.props.time).then(() =>
        this._removeElement()
      );
    };

    _fadeOut = time => {
      this.setState({ fadeout: true });
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, time);
      });
    };

    _removeElement = time => {
      this.setState({
        removeElement: true,
      });
    };

    render() {
      return this.state.removeElement ? null : (
        <div>
          {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}
const WrappedButton = fadeOutWrapper(Button);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```